# Can't tunnel firefox through SSH tunnel

Tags: firefox, ssh, putty, tunnel

I read the many tutorials on how to tunnel traffic via putty and configure Firefox to access web via that tunnel (Windows desktop).
The steps are simple: (A) set connection with dynamic ssh-tunnel at port, say 1010. (B) configure Firefox to use Socks5 at localhost:1010.

This solution used to work for me in the past, but for some reason does not work anymore. I get a page saying "The connection was reset... Try again"

To diagnose the problem, I downloaded curl utility for windows and then run this from command line:
`curl -socks5 localhost:1010 www.google.com`

It returned a valid HTML code of that page.
So the problem is not at the putty side, but rather something in FF.

I also tried the solution proposed in [here](https://sordidfellow.wordpress.com/2015/05/21/ssh-tunnel-for-chrome/) using chrome and didn't manage to get it work.

Does anyone has idea how to solve this out ?

**EDIT**: relevant screenshots stored [here](https://dochub.com/742538ea2a417dd7/Xo8bR5/screenshots?dt=mht6aiv289yl0at2)

Thanks,

-Moshe

Comment: how did you set it up? Post a screenshot or something. It is impossible to answer if we don't know what you set up.

Comment: Did you try unchecking "Proxy DNS when using socks5" on ff ?

Comment: Tried that as well. no success. This is quite weird since the `curl` test proves that the tunnel is set up correctly and can bring in web pages. So, this is something in the FF/Chrome app layer that prevents it from using the tunnel correctly.

Comment: Can someone guide me how to debug this problem using wireshark?  What should I be looking for in the messages going in and out the tunnel ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Socks proxy seems to work fine (PuTTY configuration equals `ssh -D 1010` and your `curl` test also succeed). Your browser configuration (SOCKSv5 to `localhost:1010`) seems ok, too.

If you are using some kind of virus protection that might be interfering with the browsers connections, try

- disabling virus protection plugins from Firefox
- using high source ports (1024 < x < 65536) instead of low port 1010

Comment: I tried with port number 8787 and receives the same behavior. Firefox has no add-ons/plugings. I simply downloaded latest version from web. 

I also tried to disable windows firewall and so success.

Comment: Any idea how can I debug what is wrong in my setup ?  I have no clue of what went wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more probably with your proxy settings than with Firefox, because the way you test it with Curl is not valid and will succeed even when the proxy is off. The correct command is either `curl --socks5 localhost:1010 www.google.com` (note the double dash instead of a single one) or (more modern style of doing the same thing) `curl --proxy socks5://localhost:1010 www.google.com`.

You also probably want to pass DNS through the proxy as well, by using `--socks5-hostname` or `socks5h://`.

As to speculate on the question itself: It is possible to disable port forwarding on the server, so if you're not the administrator, try to check whether the policy might have changed.